# How does exponential smoothing work?

Tags: statistics

\begin{aligned}s_{t}&=\alpha x_{t}+(1-\alpha )s_{t-1}\\[3pt]&=\alpha x_{t}+\alpha (1-\alpha )x_{t-1}+(1-\alpha )^{2}s_{t-2}\\[3pt]&=\alpha \left[x_{t}+(1-\alpha )x_{t-1}+(1-\alpha )^{2}x_{t-2}+(1-\alpha )^{3}x_{t-3}+\cdots +(1-\alpha )^{t-1}x_{1}\right]+(1-\alpha )^{t}x_{0}.\end{aligned}

So basically that's the formula of simple exponential smoothing, taken from wikipedia, but I can't understand how the substitution works, where does the `(1−)^2 ... (1−)^3 .. (1−)^t-1` comes from, where does the power comes from?  Also where does the big [ ... ] comes from too?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
$$s_t = \alpha x_t + (1-\alpha)s_{t-1}$$
Then using:
$$s_{t-1} = \alpha x_{t-1} + (1-\alpha)s_{t-2}$$
and substituting yields:
$$s_t = \alpha x_t + (1-\alpha)(\alpha x_{t-1} + (1-\alpha)s_{t-2})$$
And so on.

Comment: thanks, but where does the [x1 ... ] + (1-.. the square parentheses from the last line comes from? this part eludes me.

Comment: @MM You just expand till you get to $x_0$. Basically apply this procedure recursively. That means that in the expression above you substitue with the expression for $s_{t-2}$ then you get an expression with $s_{t-3}$, you substitute that too etc.